# Бот не обращает внимания на других людей в ивенте on_message discord py

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py, словарь

Я делаю фильтр матов на аккаунте. Это selfhost бот и в ивенте on_message он обращает внимание на мои сообщения, но на сообщения других людей не отвечает. код:

```
from discord import message
from discord.ext import commands


token = 'token аккаунта'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='*', self_bot=True, intents=discord.Intents.all())
with open('BadWords.txt', 'r') as f:
    global badwords
    words = f.read()
    badwords = words.split()


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content
    for word in badwords:
        if word in msg:
            await message.reply("Не матерись, не оскорбляй других людей!")
            print("1")

client.run(token, bot=False)
```

Файл BadWord.txt выглядит вот так:
`test test2 test3` и тд

Answer (score 0):

селф-ботинг на discord.py - это клоунада.
используй другие библиотеки
(но помни что это нарушение Discord ToS).
удачного дня!

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]